# Neo4j Import tool - Console output meaning

Tags: import, neo4j, console

What does the console output of the [Neo4j import](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/import-tool.html) tool mean?

Example lines:

`[INPUT--------------PROPERTIES(2)======|WRITER: W:71.]  3M`

`[INPUT------|PREPARE(|RELATIO||] 49M`

`[Relationship --> Relationship + counts-------]282M`

When I try to import a large dataset through this tool, it seems that at 248M, importing is hanging in the ‘calculate dense nodes’ step. What exactly does 'calculating dense nodes' do?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a thread dump at that point in time? It would be of immense help. Calculate dense nodes figures out before the importing of relationships which relationship chains will have a dense representation. Looking at your output though it seems like the import got passed that step, no?

Comment: Looking at the log file, it seems that one of the end points(let's call it node x) in a relationship have not been imported. The CSV file has node x, but for some reason it is not imported. When I tried to import ONLY the nodes, I found out the following: out of 24 million nodes in my CSV file, around 150k has not been imported. Is there any way for me to know which nodes have been skipped? Apologies for the confusion, the example lines are from a import that succeeded. I wanted to know what the output meant. Thanks!

Comment: Or, is it possible to skip the relationships that don't have a matching start or end node?

Comment: Oh, that's unexpected that nodes are just not imported. As the main author if the import tool, would it be possible for me to have a look at that node input file? If I had it I'd most likely be able to figure out what's going wrong. Perhaps using some online file sharing, outside of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some offline discussion, it seems that most, if not all "missing" nodes were due to one line in the CSV file had a property starting with quotation `"` but did not contain the end quote. This resulted in the parser reading until the next quote, i.e. through new-lines, thinking that it still read that same property value for that node.

It would be great with some sort of detection for such missing quotes, but that's not straight-forward given that it might mess with nodes/relationships actually spanning multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks Mattias! By removing the unbalanced quotes, I managed to import the entire dataset! Would really appreciate if you can also help me understand the meaning of the console output - I'm interested in calculating for every one million objects(nodes/edges), how many objects were imported per second. Also, is there a way I can configure the allocated memory in this import tool?

Comment: There have been others asking about how to interpret the output. I'll write a page about it in the neo4j manual so that everyone can see that.

Also there's no way to configure memory usage, the import tool manages that by itself and uses the available memory to its best ability. It doesn't use memory mapping, nor does it need it since it writes sequentiall to disk.

Answer (score 2):

The import stages are:

1. Nodes
2. Prepare node index
3. Calculate dense nodes
4. Node --> Relationship Sparse
5. Relationship --> Relationship Sparse
6. Node counts
7. Relationship counts

As for interpreting the statistics, I guess @mattias-persson wrote it [in the Neo4J manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/command-line-usage/#import-tool-output-and-statistics). Copying it, for the record:

#### 10.1.2.5. Output and statistics

While an import is running through its different stages, some statistics and figures are printed in the console. The general interpretation of that output is to look at the horizontal line, which is divided up into sections, each section representing one type of work going on in parallel with the other sections. The wider a section is, the more time is spent there relative to the other sections, the widest being the bottleneck, also marked with *. If a section has a double line, instead of just a single line, it means that multiple threads are executing the work in that section. To the far right a number is displayed telling how many entities (nodes or relationships) have been processed by that stage.

As an example:

```
[*>:20,25 MB/s-----------|PREPARE(3)==========|RELATIONSHIP(2)===========] 16M
```

Would be interpreted as:

- `>` data being read, and perhaps parsed, at 20,25 MB/s, data that is being passed on to …​
- `PREPARE` preparing the data for …​
- `RELATIONSHIP` creating actual relationship records and …​
- `v` writing the relationships to the store. This step is not visible in this example, because it is so cheap compared to the other sections.

Observing the section sizes can give hints about where performance can be improved. In the example above, the bottleneck is the data read section (marked with >), which might indicate that the disk is being slow, or is poorly handling simultaneous read and write operations (since the last section often revolves around writing to disk).